# Installation error numpy in Qpython

Tags: qpython

In Qpython which uses Python 2.7.2; I can't install the numpy module. The message I get is: command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2

Answer (score 0):

I think it tries to install the Mac version***, which is obviously not compatible.  At least, that's what it looked like when scrolling through the CLI output when issuing the pip install numpy command using the pip script.

I don't think the numpy/scipy modules are available for Qpython for Android.  I think we're just going to have to wait.  I've been googling this same question and I have not found an answer.

***Ok, the script says it's a version for a variety of OS', just not Android. I have no idea why pip install would download it if it wasn't compatible. It doesn't make sense, so I'm obviously missing something.